# Cumulative Distribution Function problems

Tags: self-study, density-function

Let $a$ and $b$ be two positive integers. Let also $X$ be a discrete random variable
varying in

$X(\Omega)=\{1, 2, \ldots, ab\}$ such that for every $x∈X(\Omega),P[X = x]=1/a - 1/b$.

a) What conditions should $a$ and $b$ satisfy?

b) Determine the cumulative distribution function $F$ of $X$. Compute $u$ such that
$F(u)=1/2$.

c) Determine $E(X)$. Find the values of $a$ and $b$ such that $E(X) = 7/2$.

Comment: Be careful!  Please read our FAQ and the wiki for the `Homework` tag and note that questions from textbooks, like this one, are welcome *provided* you indicate what research you have done, what progress you have made, and specifically where you need help.  Without that additional information, such questions will be closed automatically.  To would-be respondents: please note that guidance is welcome, but [detailed solutions are usually not](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12/how-should-we-deal-with-obvious-homework-questions).

Answer (score 5):

Some hints: Remember that the sum over x of P[X=x] = 1.  Note that P[X=x] is not a function of x.  c) is trivial once you've solved a), so do a) first.

Comment: I will let you know what is my approach in solving it.

Comment: a) $P[X=x]=1/a−1/b$ and any probability is always $0≤P≤1$ so $0≤b-a≤ab$

Comment: b) $F(X)=P(X≤x)=∑P(X=x)=1$. $F(u)=1/2=P(U≤u)$ and can't figure out how to continue..

Comment: c) As i know $E(X)=∑XP(X)=∑xP(X=x)$ and also I can't figure out how to make this equality in terms of $a$ and $b$ only.

Comment: If you follow the first hint, Majed, you will obtain a more definite condition on $a$ and $b$.  Concerning (b), note that $F(x)=\Pr(X\le x)=\sum_{y\le x}\Pr(X=y)$ is not equal to $1$ in general.  (Observe the lower case $x$ in $F(x)$, too.)  You can solve this one without using (a) simply by exploiting the constancy of the probability.  To get a solution, you will have to assume $ab$ is even (which is something that can be proven from the result of (a)).

Comment: +1 for posting a useful set of hints that gracefully addresses our objective of providing helpful replies to stimulate thought.